# Should I disable extensions prior to upgrading CiviCRM?

Tags: extension, upgrade

I couldn't spot anything on this in the upgrade instructions, and as it's something that could affect lots of people, I thought I'd ask the question here.

When upgrading CiviCRM, what is considered best practice regarding extensions? Should they be disabled prior to the upgrade?

If, as a result of upgrading Civi, one or more of my installed extensions is no longer compatible, what's the best procedure to follow? Should I attempt to update/upgrade extensions to a compatible version before or after upgrading CiviCRM?

Answer (score 6):

In general, I'd recommend no.

Some extensions - literally - may not be reinstallable if they aren't qualified for that version of Civi.

My recommendation: **TAKE BACKUPS!!!** Then don't disable extensions and just go ahead with the upgrade.

Comment: I agree - some extensions crash when disable so I've stopped doing that. As JohnFF says, take a backup